# Can constant expression be double type instead of integral only?

Tags: c++

From 《c++ primer,4th》,there is a sentence

> A constant expression is an expression of integral type that the compiler can evaluate at compile time.

double,long type won't be OK?

Comment: In many contexts, the constant is required to be a integral constant and a floating point constant won't do.  Note that `long` is an integral type; it just isn't the `int` type.

Comment: so,only integral type will be ok?

Comment: It will depend on the context; without knowing a lot more about the paragraph where the sentence occurs, I'm not willing to pontificate further.  If the discussion gets into `constexpr`, I'm even less willing to make statements.  There's a reason I made a comment; I'm not sure it is good enough to be an answer.  I think it is mostly valid, but I'm not sure it is absolutely valid.

Comment: @redd no, a `constexpr` constant expression can be of other types as well, but often constant expressions are used to tell the size of something, hence they are most often of integral type. However, that is not always the case, hence the book asserting that it is is simply wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) page, you can make a `constexpr` of any type that has a trivial destructor and is either an aggregate or has a `constexpr` constructor, provided this holds true for every base class as well. In other words, any primitive type can be, in addition to user defined types that follow the rules.

So, yes, you can have `constexpr` expressions with type `double` (`long` is an integral type so the book didn't challenge its `constexpr`-iness).

Answer (score -2):

String constants apply, like:

const std::string s( "this is a constant expression" );

Also,

const double x( 0.25 );

where x is a const double, and 0.25 is a constant expression.

Comment: There is a huge difference between `const` and `constexpr`. The OP is talking about `constexpr`, not `const`.

Comment: You are creating `const` objects, not `constexpr`s.

Comment: There are both, constant expressions are used to initialize these const objects, are they not? They OP inquired as to whether or not doubles might be usable, and here I show both doubles and string constant expressions. Further, something like const int n; can be used as a constant expression in defining a template, such as T<n> where n, in that case, is a constant expression.

Comment: That is not true. A `constexpr` must be evaulatable at compile time. A `const` does not need that additional constraint. A `const` variable is not required to be evaluatable at compile time. The only requirement is for a variable to be `const` is that it is initialized (which could be done at run time) and its value cannot be changed after that.

Comment: Sorry R Sahu, I had a comment started and was interrupted here, deleted it...starting again: For reference, look at cppreference.com on constant expressions. In a long, detailed discussion they give an example: const int cn; std::array< int, cn > a; in this case, cn is a constexpr, where std:array requires an integer, cn will suffice as a constexpr. Further, the OP asked if double, long types were not ok - they are as they can be evaluated at compile time. The OP may have thought integral types meant integers, but that's not the case. It includes types like long, double, char, etc.

Comment: Try compiling `constexpr std::string s("this is a constant expression");`. Hopefully what I am trying to say will make sense.